# create new variable c#

Tags: c#, variables

Let say I want to use

```
str.Split[' '].ElementAt(0) 10 times in my method.
```

Should I create a string variable called strSplit or just keep using str.Split[' '].ElementAt(0)? Is there a performance issue?

Comment: Yes, you should store it in a variable. There is perf issue when you're executing this stuff multiple times expecting the same result to be returned. Just store it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Memory is cheap. *Really* cheap.

So are CPU cycles.

Your current method will consume less memory (more while each call to `Split` has not been GC'd, but you don't store the result) by a *tiny* amount. It will consume far more CPU cycles though, especially because the GC has to collect all the temp variables created by `Split`. In reality, its not going to matter. You won't see the performance difference.

For good practice, store it off in a variable. The memory used will be inconsequential, and your code will be much cleaner and more efficient (even if you don't see it!)

Comment: Well, assuming he has 10 values, his way is going to create 100 array elements.  Why do that, when it is easily avoided by simply using the proper technique?

Comment: @RobertHarvey I agree, I just doubt he would ever notice the difference with the given calls/variable count.

Comment: The current method will (at least temporarily) consume *more* memory, not less, and force the GC collector to run more often, which could potentially eat up even more CPU cycles.

Comment: Memory will be consumed not just while `Split` runs, but until the next GC cycle.

Answer (score 1):

Use the entire returned array, not just the first element each time (unless you really only want the first element, and none of the others):

```
var result = str.Split(" ");

foreach (var splitValue in result)
{
    // do something with splitValue
}
```